# How can I add timestamp in osmdata_sf() results?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-sf, overpass-api, ropensci

When I query osm data, I want to receive the timestamp, when some object was added or changed, is it possible to include this data?
There is my query:

```
q <- opq("London",timeout = 20000) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "landuse", value="grass",value_exact = F) %>%
  osmdata_sf()
```

Then I use `q$osm_polygons` data.

in general, I want to convert this script to R:

```
[out:json][timeout:200];
{{geocodeArea:London}}->.searchArea;
way["landuse"~"grass"](area.searchArea);
(._;>;);
out meta;
```

Comment: I received the great solution from the contributor of the osm_data package on github.
There is the link from github - https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/269#issuecomment-1073748224

Comment: Hi vanhry, thank you for sharing the mpadge's code which is indeed very useful. Is this code sufficient for your needs or do you still want a way to add timestamps to each polygon of your `sf` object?

Comment: This answer on Github is solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to ignore this answer if it doesn't fit your question, as I am not sure this is exactly what you are looking for.

When you query with `osmdata` you get a list with several elements. One of them is the timestamp, but I think is the timestamp of the query, nothing else:

```r
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

q <- opq("London",timeout = 20000) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "landuse", 
                  value="grass",value_exact = F) %>%
  osmdata_sf()

timestamp <- q$meta$timestamp

timestamp
#> [1] "[ lu\\. 2 mar 2022 17:01:08 ]"

# Use in polygons
pols <- q$osm_polygons
pols$timestamp <- timestamp

head(pols)
#>          osm_id name FIXME access addr.city addr.country addr.flats
#> 4344595 4344595 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
#> 4402127 4402127 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
#> 4960175 4960175 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
#> 4960176 4960176 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
#> 5005998 5005998 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
#> 5131217 5131217 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
#>         addr.housename addr.housenumber addr.postcode addr.street addr.suburb
#> 4344595           <NA>             <NA>          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#> 4402127           <NA>             <NA>          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#> 4960175           <NA>             <NA>          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#> 4960176           <NA>             <NA>          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#> 5005998           <NA>             <NA>          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#> 5131217           <NA>             <NA>          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
#>         amenity area area.highway attraction barrier bicycle building
#> 4344595    <NA> <NA>         <NA>       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
#> 4402127    <NA> <NA>         <NA>       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
#> 4960175    <NA> <NA>         <NA>       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
#> 4960176    <NA> <NA>         <NA>       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
#> 5005998    <NA> <NA>         <NA>       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
#> 5131217    <NA> <NA>         <NA>       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
#>         building.levels complete created_by description  dog embankment
#> 4344595            <NA>     <NA>       <NA>        <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#> 4402127            <NA>     <NA>       <NA>        <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#> 4960175            <NA>     <NA>       <NA>        <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#> 4960176            <NA>     <NA>       <NA>        <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#> 5005998            <NA>     <NA>       <NA>        <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#> 5131217            <NA>     <NA>       <NA>        <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#>         emergency est_height fence_type fictional.leisure foot garden.type golf
#> 4344595      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>
#> 4402127      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>
#> 4960175      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>
#> 4960176      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>
#> 5005998      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>
#> 5131217      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>
#>         height highway landcover landuse layer leaf_cycle leaf_type leisure
#> 4344595   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   grass  <NA>       <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
#> 4402127   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   grass  <NA>       <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
#> 4960175   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   grass  <NA>       <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
#> 4960176   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   grass  <NA>       <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
#> 5005998   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   grass  <NA>       <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
#> 5131217   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   grass  <NA>       <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
#>         level level.ref  lit man_made material mown name.de name.en name.es
#> 4344595  <NA>      <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#> 4402127  <NA>      <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#> 4960175  <NA>      <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#> 4960176  <NA>      <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#> 5005998  <NA>      <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#> 5131217  <NA>      <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#>         name.no name.ru natural note operator power proposed.construction  ref
#> 4344595    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>                  <NA> <NA>
#> 4402127    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>                  <NA> <NA>
#> 4960175    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>                  <NA> <NA>
#> 4960176    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>                  <NA> <NA>
#> 5005998    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>                  <NA> <NA>
#> 5131217    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>                  <NA> <NA>
#>         roof.shape service smokefree source source.alt source.name species
#> 4344595       <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 4402127       <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 4960175       <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 4960176       <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 5005998       <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 5131217       <NA>    <NA>      <NA>   <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#>         sport surface tourism verge wall water website wheelchair wikidata
#> 4344595  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#> 4402127  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#> 4960175  <NA>   grass    <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#> 4960176  <NA>   grass    <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#> 5005998  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#> 5131217  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#>         wikipedia  zoo
#> 4344595      <NA> <NA>
#> 4402127      <NA> <NA>
#> 4960175      <NA> <NA>
#> 4960176      <NA> <NA>
#> 5005998      <NA> <NA>
#> 5131217      <NA> <NA>
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       geometry
#> 4344595 -0.1652129, -0.1651560, -0.1651036, -0.1651275, -0.1651710, -0.1651492, -0.1651205, -0.1650602, -0.1653027, -0.1654683, -0.1656305, -0.1657699, -0.1659660, -0.1659822, -0.1659633, -0.1658668, -0.1656550, -0.1654632, -0.1652129, 51.3742634, 51.3742755, 51.3742750, 51.3741929, 51.3739946, 51.3738555, 51.3737819, 51.3736785, 51.3737734, 51.3738206, 51.3738482, 51.3738567, 51.3738218, 51.3738403, 51.3738861, 51.3739581, 51.3740887, 51.3741746, 51.3742634
#> 4402127                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.0613193, -0.0600375, -0.0601011, -0.0615835, -0.0615599, -0.0613193, 51.6537986, 51.6535366, 51.6526077, 51.6526670, 51.6527539, 51.6537986
#> 4960175                                                                                                                                                                         -0.1720485, -0.1719397, -0.1722486, -0.1722973, -0.1722377, -0.1722032, -0.1721640, -0.1721372, -0.1721310, -0.1721433, -0.1721618, -0.1720485, 51.4972628, 51.4970547, 51.4969916, 51.4970908, 51.4971093, 51.4971232, 51.4971477, 51.4971737, 51.4971949, 51.4972222, 51.4972430, 51.4972628
#> 4960176                                                                                                                                                 -0.1723924, -0.1727108, -0.1728035, -0.1726872, -0.1726907, -0.1726904, -0.1726738, -0.1726459, -0.1725957, -0.1725449, -0.1724884, -0.1724326, -0.1723924, 51.4969669, 51.4969106, 51.4971294, 51.4971517, 51.4971333, 51.4971139, 51.4970902, 51.4970792, 51.4970646, 51.4970605, 51.4970621, 51.4970654, 51.4969669
#> 5005998                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -0.0870457, -0.0868122, -0.0865329, -0.0865281, -0.0865614, -0.0875218, -0.0870457, 51.4453207, 51.4453062, 51.4452885, 51.4450222, 51.4445561, 51.4445895, 51.4453207
#> 5131217                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -0.1982559, -0.1976423, -0.1976439, -0.1982576, -0.1982559, 51.4698145, 51.4698128, 51.4695882, 51.4695899, 51.4698145
#>                             timestamp
#> 4344595 [ lu\\. 2 mar 2022 17:01:08 ]
#> 4402127 [ lu\\. 2 mar 2022 17:01:08 ]
#> 4960175 [ lu\\. 2 mar 2022 17:01:08 ]
#> 4960176 [ lu\\. 2 mar 2022 17:01:08 ]
#> 5005998 [ lu\\. 2 mar 2022 17:01:08 ]
#> 5131217 [ lu\\. 2 mar 2022 17:01:08 ]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
os

Comment: I see you opened an issue on the package repo, just leave here for reference  https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/269

Comment: Timestamps will be the same for each node, but thank you for your answer

Comment: Yep, I see, this is not answering your question... :(